# How to select/delete all duplicate rows based on all columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wanted to select / delete all duplicate rows on multiple table. I have searched the internet for clues but all I see are queries that selects duplicate rows **based one or more column**. Like this:
`SELECT col1 count(*) from table_name group by col1 having count(*) > 1`

What I want to achieve is to select duplicate rows based on **ALL COLUMNS**, as long as all their values in each column are the same.

I am dealing with multiple tables so I want it to be generic so it could work on any tables.

Comment: Select all columns, group by all columns and apply HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the duplicates and leave the first instance of each row then you can use a sub-query within the delete and correlate on the `ROWID` pseudo-column and find the rows within each group that have a `ROW_NUMBER` greater than 1:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, /*...,*/ colN -- List all the columns
             ORDER BY ROWID
           ) AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  rn > 1
);
```

If you want to delete all copies of all duplicates then:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (
             PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, /*...,*/ colN -- List all the columns
           ) AS cnt
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  cnt > 1
);
```

Comment: getting error ORA-01446 with this SQL

Comment: @psaraj12 Change it to `ORDER BY ROWID` (or a constant) rather than `ROWNUM`.

Answer (score 0):

I have adopted MTO answer and made some corrections and more generic

```
    declare
      l_column_list varchar2(32767);
      l_table_name  varchar2(4000) := 'AAAA_DATES';
    begin
      for rec in (select column_name, column_id
                    from dba_tab_cols
                   where table_name = l_table_name
                   order by column_id) loop
        if (rec.column_id = 1) then
          l_column_list := rec.column_name;
        else
          l_column_list := l_column_list || ',' || rec.column_name;
        end if;
      end loop;

      execute immediate 'DELETE FROM ' || l_table_name ||
                        '  WHERE ROWID IN (
      SELECT ROW_id
      FROM   (
        SELECT rowid row_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY ' || l_column_list ||
                        ' ORDER BY ROWNUM
               ) AS rn
        FROM ' || l_table_name || '
      )
      WHERE  rn > 1
    )';
      dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
      commit;
    end;
```